# Adding textarea "description box" to widget [Wordpress]

Tags: php, html, wordpress, widget, textarea

My widget is showingmin my admin area but when I click it so that it can drop down so that I may enter information... it only shows the DELETE link, CLOSE link and SAVE button. the widget will not expand. I believe I am missing something in the script for the textarea causing the widget not to function properly.

```
<?php
if( !class_exists('smWidget') ):
class smWidget extends WP_Widget {

// constructor
function smWidget() {
// Give widget name here
$widget_ops = array('description' => __('Displays a selected post from a selected post type.', 'ci_theme'));

parent::WP_Widget('smWidget', $name='-= SM Item =-', $widget_ops);
}




// display widget
function widget($args, $instance) {
    extract( $args );



    $ci_post_id = $instance['postid'];

        $post_type_name = $instance['post_type_name'];

        if( empty($ci_post_id) or empty($post_type_name) )
            return;

        $q = new WP_Query( array(
            'post_type' => $post_type_name,
            'p' => $ci_post_id
        ) );

        echo $before_widget;



$title = apply_filters( 'widget_title', empty( $instance['title']) ? '' : $instance['title'], $instance, $this->id_base );

        if ($title)
            echo $before_title . $title . $after_title;

        while ( $q->have_posts() ): $q->the_post();
            global $post;




            if ( get_post_type() == 'testimonial' ) :
                ?>

<div class="testimonial-wrap">
  <div class="testimonial-inner">
    <blockquote> <i class="fa fa-quote-left"></i>
      <?php the_content(); ?>
      <cite>
      <?php the_title(); ?>
      </cite> </blockquote>
  </div>
</div>
<?php
            elseif ( get_post_type() == 'video' ) :
                ?>
<div <?php post_class('item'); ?>>
  <?php 
                        $video = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'ci_cpt_video_url', true);
                        echo wp_oembed_get($video);
                    ?>
</div>
<?php
            else :
                get_template_part('loop', 'item');
            endif;
        endwhile;
        wp_reset_postdata();

        echo $after_widget;

    }

    function update($new_instance, $old_instance)
    {
        $instance = $old_instance;
        $instance['title'] = sanitize_text_field($new_instance['title']);
        $instance['post_type_name'] = sanitize_key($new_instance['post_type_name']);
        $instance['postid'] = absint($new_instance['postid']);
        $instance['teatarea'] = absint($new_instance['textarea']);
        return $instance;
    }











function form($instance){

        $defaults = array(
            'title' => '',
            'post_type_name' => 'post',
            'postid' => '',
            'textarea' => '',
        );


        $instance = wp_parse_args( (array) $instance, $defaults );

        $title = $instance['title'];
        $post_type_name = $instance['post_type_name'];
        $post_id = $instance['postid'];
        $textarea = $instance['textarea'];

        ?>
<p>
  <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('title'); ?>">
    <?php _e('Title (optional):', 'ci_theme'); ?>
  </label>
  <input id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('title'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('title'); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr($title); ?>" class="widefat" />
</p>
<?php

        $post_types = get_post_types( array('public' => true), 'objects' );
        unset($post_types['attachment'], $post_types['slider']);
        ?>
<p>
<label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('post_type_name'); ?>">
<?php _e('Show posts from this post type:', 'ci_theme'); ?>
<label>
</p>
<?php ?>
<select name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('post_type_name'); ?>" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('post_type_name'); ?>" >
  <?php
            foreach( $post_types as $key => $pt )
            {
        ?>
  <option value="<?php echo esc_attr($key); ?>" <?php selected($key, $post_type_name); ?>><?php echo $pt->labels->name; ?></option>
  <?php
            }
        ?>
</select>
<img src="<?php echo get_child_or_parent_file_uri('/panel/img/ajax-loader-16x16.gif'); ?>" class="loading_posts" style="display: none;">
<?php
        ?>
<p></p>
<?php
        ?>
<p>
  <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('postid'); ?>">
    <?php _e('Select a post to show:', 'ci_theme'); ?>
  </label>
</p>
<?php
        ?>
<p class="ci_widget_post_type_posts_dropdown">
  <?php
        wp_dropdown_posts(
            array(
                'post_type' => $post_type_name,
                'show_option_none' => '&nbsp;',
                'selected' => $post_id,
                'class' => 'widefat'
            ),
            $this->get_field_name('postid')
        );
        ?>
</p>
<?php 

        ?>
<p>
  <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('textarea'); ?>">
    <?php _e('Description:', 'ci_theme'); ?>
  </label>
  <textarea class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('textarea'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('textarea'); ?>" rows="7" cols="20" ><?php echo $textarea; ?></textarea>
</p>
<?php
    }


static function _ajax_get_posts()
    {
        $post_type_name = sanitize_key($_POST['post_type_name']);
        $name_field = esc_attr($_POST['name_field']);

        $str = wp_dropdown_posts(
            array(
                'echo' => false,
                'post_type' => $post_type_name,
                'show_option_none' => '&nbsp;',
                'class' => 'widefat'
            ),
            $name_field
        );

        echo $str;
        die;
    }

} // class

register_widget('smWidget');

add_action('wp_ajax_ci_widget_post_type_ajax_get_posts', 'smWidget::_ajax_get_posts');

endif; // !class_exists

?>
```